# deployment failed with Netlify on my Angular 8 project

Tags: angular, netlify

I can not deploy my project in the logs he says that ng: not found why?

Thank you.

[Netlify log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAvyE.jpg)

```
{
  "name": "cat-mash-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "build:prod": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "mock": "mockserver -p 8080 -m mocks",
    "heroku-postbuild": "ng build --prod"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/fire": "^5.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.9",
    "@netlify-builder/deploy": "^2.0.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "gatsby": "^2.17.10",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.8",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "enhanced-resolve": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}

{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "CatMashProject": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/CatMashProject",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": false,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/_redirects"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "CatMashProject:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "CatMashProject:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "CatMashProject:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "CatMashProject:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "CatMashProject:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "@netlify-builder/deploy:deploy",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/CatMashProject",
            "netlifyToken": "2cb8aeb5-62e2-472b-be5b-3da87a7f572c",
            "siteId": "d1865c183ce06c9cd4570036934c8ab93d4c523b73fe76493816ea9aa298ac44"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "CatMashProject"
}
```

Comment: Please format your code

Comment: you should install `@angular/cli` globally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing, your question is not proper exclamatory.

I noticed from your github repositoy that your angular project is not at root of repository. So, you have to set **Base directory** to `CatMashProject` in **build settings** of Netlify

**Build settings:**

**Base directory**: CatMashProject

**Build command**: ng build --prod

**Publish directory**: CatMashProject/dist/CatMashProject